# How do you beat a mission in under a minute?

Tags: creeper-world-3-arc-eternal

Creeper World 3: Arc Eternal has been described as "building a spiderweb to fight a slushy": you're building a network of various devices and weapons, connected so that they can get power from a central store. You're fighting against the Creeper, a sort of Gray Goo that slowly flows across the landscape and destroys all in its path.

Whenever you beat a mission, you can submit your time to a central server. I usually manage to score at about the "top third this week" spot on any given mission, but on the "fastest of all time" section, there's usually a collection of people who beat the mission in under a minute – the shortest is usually in the 30-second range, and then there's a string of people who took longer, at reasonable intervals. It doesn't look like hacking – in that case, I'd expect a bunch of fastest-possible scores bunched together, and then everyone else much worse off.

What technique does it take to beat a mission in under a minute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am, alas, wrong. Cheaters are moderately-frequent, spurred at least partially by the existence of a badge to "score in the top 10, on a map that has been played at least 20 times." The times are spread out semi-randomly because some people cheat by sending a fraudulent report to the server, and some other people cheat by playing with trainers to give them more resources (which gives them an excellent, but not perfect, score).

Source: [lots](http://steamcommunity.com/app/280220/discussions/0/522730701446657142/) [of](http://steamcommunity.com/app/280220/discussions/0/613937942970998008/) [people](http://knucklecracker.com/forums/index.php?topic=888.msg7548#msg7548) [complaining](http://knucklecracker.com/forums/index.php?topic=833.msg7483#msg7483). Apparently, the only way to know whether someone is cheating on a map is to:

1. Be very good at the game
2. Play the map
3. If someone beat your score by a large margin, they're probably cheating. Or they figured out a clever way to win, and/or you're not as good as you thought you were.

Alternatively, find the names of a few top-tier players. If they've played the map you're looking at, then anything better than those times is likely the result of cheating.

Comment: This is unfortunately a fairly recurrent thing through many different games. People just want [their name at the top of the leader board](http://i.imgur.com/XllpB2f.jpg), not to get the feeling of achievement by finishing the game properly.

Answer (score 4):

I won't say this in every scenario, but typically scores/times below 50 seconds that do not have a forge, or "consistently" flat ground will most likely be cheated scores.

Without any forge upgrades, it takes roughly that long without any energy.

If it's below 20 seconds, it's 99.9% cheated. For storymode missions, it's 100% cheated.

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything to the existing ones, and should probably be a comment on the other answer.

Comment: I don't have permission to comment on them

Comment: The travails of a new user :) Ask a few good questions (or answer them), and you'll get to 50 rep before you know it!